# How many points determine an algebraic surface ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We know that 5 points in general position determine a conic section uniquely. I wonder if there is a generalization. Consider the equation 
$F(x_1,\dots, x_n) =0$ where $F$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ (over $R$). Is there a 
(sharp) bound on the number of points $(x_1,...,x_n)$ (in general position) which uniquely determines $F$ ?

Comment: Well, basically the reason why 5 general points determines a conic is that the space of quadratic polynomials in three variables is 6 dimensional (it is spanned by $x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz$), and scaling the quadratic does not change the zero-set.

More generally the space of degree $d$ polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^n$ has dimension ${n+d \choose d}$ and so ${n+d \choose d}-1$ general points determine the hypersurface uniquely. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has essentially been given by J. C. Ottem in a comment. I just put it here (with a couple details) so that the question is "answered".

The space of degree $d$ polynomials in n+1 variables has dimension $\binom{n+d}{d}$ (coefficient count), so hypersurfaces of degree d in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are parameterized by a projective space of dimension $N:=\binom{n+d}{d}-1$. Asking that the hypersurface goes through a given point is a linear equation on the coefficients of polynomials.

If the base field (or domain) is infinite, then the conditions imposed by general points are independent. You prove this by induction on the number of points: assume that hypersurfaces of degree d in $\mathbb{P}^n$ through $k-1 < N-1$ general points are parameterized by $\mathbb{P}^{N-k+1}$. **EDIT**: Choose one of these hypersurfaces $X$; it does *not* contain all of the points in $\mathbb{P}^n$, as the base field is infinite. So if the $k$-th point is out of $X$ (which we can assume as the points are general) the parameter space of hypersurfaces containing all $k$ points is strictly conained in $\mathbb{P}^{N-k+1}$, which means the last condition is linearly independent and defines a hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^{N-k}$.

So $N$ is the number of general points that uniquely determine a hypersurface of degree $d$.

Comment: @quim

Thanks. I still have problem understanding your argument. When you wrote "Since there are infinitely many points in $P^n$, not all of them belong to one of the given family of hypersurfaces", what family do you refer to ?

Our setting is that we have $N$ general points given and want to show that the conditions imposed are independent. These points are given, so I am a bit confused with the next sentence "Since there are infinitely many points,.... Taking one....." as well (as we don't have the freedom to take an arbitrary point). 


Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it is clearer now. The points are assumed to be in general position, otherwise the result would be false.

Comment: @quim

So all we need is that there is one $X$ in the family that  does not contain the $k$th point ? or we need it to hold for all $X$'s ? (the later cannot be true) 

So would the precise claim be: There is one $X$ going through the first $k-1$ points and does not contain the $k$th point ?

You seems to suggest any $X$ may work ? 


Comment: Exactly, it is enough that one X does not contain the k-th point to ensure that the k-th condition is relevant.
Fix a set of k-1 points such that the set of hypersurfaces X of degree n through them is a $\mathbb{P}^{N-k+1}$. Let $Z\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be the base locus (ie, the intersection of all those hypersurfaces). Then every point q in the complement of $Z$ works as $k$-th point, in the sense that the condition "going through q" is independent of the previous conditions (because at least one X misses q). Since Z is a Zariski closed proper subset, you are done.

Comment: So, once the first k-1 points are fixed (and assuming they impose independent conditions) the "general position" hypothesis on the k-th can be made precise by requiring that q does not belong to Z. If you want, it is possible from this to obtain an explicit (somewhat ugly) description of the Zariski-closed proper subset V of $(\mathbb{P}^n)^k$ of k-uples of points that impose k non-independent linear conditions. Then, not being in V is exactly what "in general position" means, for this particular result.

Comment: Let me stress the key point again: the base locus Z is not only Zariski closed (this is obvious) but also a proper subset. It is proper because it is contained in (many, hence at least one) hypersurface, which is a proper subset if the base domain is infinite. (If you start with a finite base field, for high degrees N will be bigger than the total number of points in the projective n-space).

Comment: Could it be that the definition for "general position" is just the simple definition in linear algebra ?  I  guess this may not be enough in general,  but it is so in the conic case. Is it just a coincidence ? Is there any counter example ? 

Comment: No it is not, and this is easy to see. 9 points in general position determine a cubic plane curve uniquely. But if they lie on a conic, then the cubic is not unique (actually, the cubic degenerates into the union of the conic and a line, which is arbitrary). Of course they can lie on a conic and no three of them be aligned.

Comment: I see. Would be it tempting to assume that the polynomial that defines the surface is irreducible then ? 

Comment: Yes and no. It is true that for points in general position the polynomial turns out to be irreducible, in characteristic zero at least, but this is harder to prove (look for Bertini theorems). It is false that for every position of the points such that the hypersurface is unique, it is irreducible. I.e., "general position" translates into different Zariski open subsets for uniqueness and irreducibility, the latter being smaller. (This happens already for conics: if no four points out of five are aligned, the conic through them is unique; if no three are aligned, it is unique and irreducible).

Comment: Let me ask something even more specific and perhaps simpler. Assume that the polynomial is irreducible, and given N points on the hypersurface  in general position (now general here is just linearly general; no three points on a line, no 4 on a plane etc). Is it true that this set of N points 
determines the surface uniquely ? (In other words, the conditions 
on the coefficients implied by them are linearly independent.) 